# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' , Poetry add mysql-python error On MacOS

Tags: python

I got some wrong feedback for `poetry add mysql-python` run at MacOS 12.3 Apple M1

```
poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.6
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/samzonglu/Git/PycharmProjects/ym_api/.venv
Valid:          True

System
Platform: darwin
OS:       posix
Python:   /Users/samzonglu/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6
```

[image]